# Google Ads DeveloperToken

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, adsense

I want to update our code for the new Google Ads API but I cant find the API Center in Google Ads Dashboard with the main account.

When I open the url to API Center than came this message: Only administrative account users have access to the API Center. For more information, see the API login guide

Has anyone a idea or is there another way to get the Developer Token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke. I find my mistake.

First step is go to the following page https://ads.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/

Than click on the button "Create manager account". Now you can crate a manager account and become in this Google Ads account the navigation point "API center".

Now you can create a developer token.

Comment: Can you also mention how to use the developer token? Is it possible to use developer token without OAuth2 ... with a service account maybe to access ads api ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a demo app that is integrated with Google Ads, check out this video tutorial and check the description section for more resources such as frontend code repo, backend code repo, technical guide explaining how to build every feature. Video tutorial --> https://youtu.be/WvP3vtc_o7Q